# Pandas `period_range` gives strange results

Tags: python, pandas

I want a pandas period range with 25 hours offset, and I saw there are two ways to do this (see [here](https://github.com/AileenNielsen/TimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/blob/master/1.%20Dates%20%26%20Times.ipynb)):

The first way is to use `freq=25H`, which I tried, and gave me the right answer:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.period_range(start='2016-01-01 10:00', freq = '25H', periods = 10)
```

and the result is

```
PeriodIndex(['2016-01-01 10:00', '2016-01-02 11:00', '2016-01-03 12:00',
             '2016-01-04 13:00', '2016-01-05 14:00', '2016-01-06 15:00',
             '2016-01-07 16:00', '2016-01-08 17:00', '2016-01-09 18:00',
             '2016-01-10 19:00'],
            dtype='int64', freq='25H')
```

The second way, using `freq=1D1H`, however, gave me a rather strange result:

```
pd.period_range(start='2016-01-01 10:00', freq = '1D1H', periods = 10)
```

and I got

```
 PeriodIndex(['1971-12-02 01:00', '1971-12-02 02:00', '1971-12-02 03:00',
              '1971-12-02 04:00', '1971-12-02 05:00', '1971-12-02 06:00',
              '1971-12-02 07:00', '1971-12-02 08:00', '1971-12-02 09:00',
              '1971-12-02 10:00'],
            dtype='int64', freq='25H')
```

So maybe `1D1H` is not a valid way to specify frequency? how did `1971` come up? (I also tried to use use `1D1H` as frequency for the `date_range()` method, which did yield the right answer.)

```
pd.date_range('2016-01-01 10:00', freq = '1D1H', periods = 10)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-01 10:00:00', '2016-01-02 11:00:00',
               '2016-01-03 12:00:00', '2016-01-04 13:00:00',
               '2016-01-05 14:00:00', '2016-01-06 15:00:00',
               '2016-01-07 16:00:00', '2016-01-08 17:00:00',
               '2016-01-09 18:00:00', '2016-01-10 19:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='25H')
```

EDIT: it appears that with `period_range()`, though `freq=1D1H` doesn't work, `freq=1H1D` does. The reason is still unknown.

EDIT2: this has been identified as a bug, see the answer below.

Comment: The output seems buggy for the input, admittedly, but where did you see that this input is legal? I've never seen a two-term frequency specification like this.

Comment: It's from a pandas time series tutorial from scipy 2016, the notebook is [here](https://github.com/AileenNielsen/TimeSeriesAnalysisWithPython/blob/master/1.%20Dates%20%26%20Times.ipynb). If you search for `1d1h` you can find the exact location.

Comment: OK, added it to the question. In general, you might want to link to sources on which you're basing a question.

Comment: [Combining Aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#combining-aliases) is a thing, apparently!

Comment: `pd.period_range('2016-01-01 10:10', freq = '1H1D', periods = 10)` works OK!

Comment: Ha! this has been even more interesting. So `1H1D` works alright but `1D1H` doesn't, any explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug has already been identified and [reported on GitHub](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13730).

EDIT: [A fix](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/81819b7aa2537469448fbaeb4cd9e3d500f4e2a1) has been merged and will be included in v0.19.